# How to compare pixel colors

Tags: image-processing, image-comparison

I have a background image and a new image that I wish to compare pixel by pixel.

I will call these I1 and I2. Suppose the color at x,y in I1 is (r1,g1,b1) and I2 is (r2,g2,b2).

Now I find this empirically of the light settings I had in my room, that when r1 is in the range of r2 +/- 25 or b1 is in the range of b2 +/- 25 or g1 is in the range of g2 +/- 25, pixel at x,y in I1 and I2 are identical.

This 25 is the threshold for my room how do I estimate this threshold dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking towards color quantization. Everyone can see a different " identical. " as far as I know there's no pleasing everyone.

[An Overview of Color Quantization Techniques](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~matt/courses/cs563/talks/color_quant/CQindex.html)

[Ux StackExchange Monitor colors and the human eye](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30127/monitors-display-more-colors-than-human-eye-can-distinguish)